# TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError

Tags: web3.js

```
TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError: Signature BKS8GgYnYwgnAGhxk8yeLmVCctq8BMWHnDfAqTvX3VWxyeG6AcgxNQd7taGLzBQ8bXLWJwNsiaxEsnimi3hNvnZ has expired: block height exceeded.
    at Connection._callee30$ (/home/hackerboy/solana-programs/ai-nft-generator/.yarn/cache/@solana-web3.js-npm-1.78.4-a8d1cdae74-e1c44c6cbe.zip/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:3956:15)
    at tryCatch (/home/hackerboy/solana-programs/ai-nft-generator/.yarn/cache/@babel-runtime-npm-7.22.10-2771d0ecab-524d41517e.zip/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:44:17)
    at Generator.<anonymous> (/home/hackerboy/solana-programs/ai-nft-generator/.yarn/cache/@babel-runtime-npm-7.22.10-2771d0ecab-524d41517e.zip/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:128:22)
    at Generator.next (/home/hackerboy/solana-programs/ai-nft-generator/.yarn/cache/@babel-runtime-npm-7.22.10-2771d0ecab-524d41517e.zip/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:69:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/home/hackerboy/solana-programs/ai-nft-generator/.yarn/cache/@babel-runtime-npm-7.22.10-2771d0ecab-524d41517e.zip/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
    at _next (/home/hackerboy/solana-programs/ai-nft-generator/.yarn/cache/@babel-runtime-npm-7.22.10-2771d0ecab-524d41517e.zip/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:22:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  signature: 'BKS8GgYnYwgnAGhxk8yeLmVCctq8BMWHnDfAqTvX3VWxyeG6AcgxNQd7taGLzBQ8bXLWJwNsiaxEsnimi3hNvnZ'
}
```

Getting this error when trying to execute this Transaction. Not sure why?
I'm testing on localnet.
Full code here: https://github.com/raghav-rama/ai-nft-generator/blob/master/tests/ai-nft-generator.ts#L297

```
const enclaveSigner = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
console.log(`enclaveSigner`, enclaveSigner.publicKey.toBase58());
const rewardAddress =
  await switchboardG.program.mint.getOrCreateAssociatedUser(
    payer.publicKey
  );
functionVerifyIxn = attestationTypes.functionVerify(
  switchboardG.program,
  {
    params: {
      observedTime: new anchor.BN(unixTimestamp()),
      nextAllowedTimestamp: new anchor.BN(unixTimestamp() + 100),
      isFailure: false,
      mrEnclave: Array.from(MRENCLAVE),
    },
  },
  {
    function: functionAccountG.publicKey,
    functionEnclaveSigner: enclaveSigner.publicKey,
    verifier: switchboardG.verifier.publicKey,
    verifierSigner: switchboardG.verifier.signer.publicKey,
    attestationQueue: switchboardG.attestationQueue.publicKey,
    escrowWallet: functionAccountData.escrowWallet,
    escrowTokenWallet: functionAccountData.escrowTokenWallet,
    receiver: rewardAddress,
    verifierPermission: switchboardG.verifier.permissionAccount.publicKey,
    tokenProgram: anchor.utils.token.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  }
);
const preTransaction = new Transaction().add(functionVerifyIxn);
preTransaction.recentBlockhash = (
  await connection.getLatestBlockhash(commitment)
).blockhash;
const txId = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
  connection,
  preTransaction,
  [enclaveSigner, switchboardG.verifier.signer],
  { skipPreflight: true }
);
```

Comment: I believe skipPreflight defaults preflightCommitment to finalized, and your commitment in the code on GH shows confirmed. I would set the preflightCommitment to confirmed as well.

Answer (score 3):

In order to confirm a transaction whose lifetime is specified by a blockhash, you need two things:

- the blockhash
- the block height until which that blockhash is valid

The `getLatestBlockhash()` method gets *both* of those things for you. In your code, you throw the second thing out.

Instead, create your transaction like this:

```
const latestBlockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash(commitment);
const preTransaction = new Transaction(latestBlockhash).add(functionVerifyIxn);
```